# Can a wireless client e.g. wireless laptop connect to a wireless bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking

If I have a wireless bridge, can a wireless client such as a wireless laptop connect to it or can only wired clients e.g. a PC connect to a wireless bridge?

Comment: Connect to the device itself to change settings?

Comment: Make and model?

Comment: @Dave M - It isn't specific to a make and model but rather generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wireless bridge forms a connection from AP to AP, and isn't a ratified standard, so implementations can vary.

There are three main types:

1. Wireless Bridge - only packets between APs go over the air, so no wireless clients permitted to either AP, they must be wired
2. Client Bridge - one AP acts as a wireless client to another AP.  The "headend" AP is configured as a normal AP, and so permits connections from wireless clients.  The Client AP is no longer an AP as the network card is used just like a network card in a laptop - for outgoing connection.  However, the wireless connection is bridged to the lan ports, so you can have wired clients at the Client AP end.
3. Repeater - this is the same as (2) except the Client AP retains its AP functionality and so you can have wireless clients.

It isn't always clear which of these are supported when something supports a wireless bridge due to the lack of standards.  [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers) tries to support all three.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I don't quite follow the difference between a wireless bridge and client bridge if they both only allow wired clients.

Comment: Take it when you say `However, the wireless connection is bridged to the lan ports` you were referring to switch ports? Is that right?

Comment: Yeah I am using "lan ports" and "switch ports" interchangeably here.  Note that (2) allows wireless clients and (1) doesn't.  So they are different, at least at the head-end.

Comment: Okay. Just to make sure I understand. The 'headend' Access Point is connected to the modem. The client Access Point is connected to the 'headend' Access Point when it acts as a wireless client. If a client bridge allows wireless connections as well as wired, how is this different to a repeater then?

Comment: It is about where the wireless clients can connect to.  In client bridge mode, the wireless clients can only connect to the headend AP.  In repeater mode, they can connect to both the headend AP and the client AP.  Client Repeater mode effectively extends the range of the wireless network by using the radio in the client AP.  Client bridge mode just uses wireless to bridge two networks, it doesn't provide any AP functionality at the Client AP end.

Comment: Silly question possibly. Why would I want to bridge 2 networks using Client Bridge mode?

Comment: You would use client bridge mode where you want to support other connections to the headend, but don't need the overhead of client repeater mode.